# struct of struct segfault

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a struct for a packet and put an ip_header and udp_header into it, but it segfaults when it gets to that part of the code . I have been stuck on this for quite a while and am stumped.

```
/* IP header struct */
struct ip_header{
    unsigned char       iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
    unsigned char       iph_tos;
    unsigned short int  iph_len;
    unsigned short int  iph_ident;
    unsigned char       iph_flag;
    unsigned short int  iph_offset;
    unsigned char       iph_ttl;
    unsigned char       iph_protocol;
    unsigned short int  iph_chksum;
    unsigned int        iph_sourceip;
    unsigned int        iph_destip; 
};

/*UDP header struct */
struct udp_header{
    unsigned short int udph_srcport;
    unsigned short int udph_destport;
    unsigned short int udph_len;
    unsigned short int udph_chksum;
};

/* Packet struct */
struct packet{
    ip_header ip_hdr;
    udp_header udp_hdr;
    string buffer;
};

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    string ip_line;
    string message_line;
    get_input( ip_line, message_line );

ip_header i = create_ip_header( address, ip_line );
udp_header u = create_udp_header();

cout << "IP len\t" << i.iph_len << endl;
cout << "UDP len\t" << u.udph_len << endl;

packet *pkt = ( struct packet* )(i.iph_len + u.udph_len + sizeof( message_line ));


//SEGFAULTS HERE
pkt->ip_hdr = i;
pkt->udp_hdr = u;
pkt->buffer = message_line;
```

Comment: Don't tag it both `c` and `c++`. `std::string` makes it only C++.

Comment: You're adding a bunch of sizes and casting that to a structure pointer. That makes absolutely no sense. You need to allocate the structure.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
packet *pkt = ( struct packet* )(i.iph_len + u.udph_len + sizeof( message_line ));
```

You can't set a pointer to the sum of a bunch of lengths and sizes, it needs to point to an allocated object. It should be:

```
packet *pkt = new packet;
```

Comment: I guess I was blindly following example code. Can you please explain why this works then?                                               `char ipbuf[8192];
struct ip_header *ip = (struct ip_header *) ipbuf;` @Barmar

Comment: `ipbuf` is an array, and an array decays to a pointer when used as a value. So you're just converting one type of pointer to another. Compare that to your original code, where none of the values are arrays.

Comment: @JohnTunisi your code is like doing `struct ip_header *ip = (struct ip_header *)8192;`